# Visual Studio Load Test redirect URL from Siteminder

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio, load-testing, web-testing

I have a security application called Siteminder. It creates unique URLS for every authentication. `HTTPS://SITE/idp/**RANDOMURLSTRING**/resumeSAML20/idp/startSSO.ping`

How can i capture the Unique URL and have the test continue to login.

A webtest assumes the next URL in the process. It does not support[Or I don't know how] a unique redirect to a random URL.  Does anyone know of a way to handle this case?

EDIT:
My Solution -- Replace the SessionID with {{SessionID}} in all the URLS and use this extraction rule

```
 public class ExtractSiteMinderCustomUrl : ExtractionRule

    {
        public string SiteMinderSessionID { get; private set; }

        // The Extract method.  The parameter e contains the web performance test context.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        public override void Extract(object sender, ExtractionEventArgs e)
        {
            //look for anchor tags with URLS
                Regex regex = new Regex("<a\\s+(?:[^>]*?\\s+)?href=\"([^\"]+\\?[^\"]+)\"");
            MatchCollection match = regex.Matches(e.Response.BodyString);
            if (match.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Match ItemMatch in match)
                {
                    if (ItemMatch.ToString().Contains("/idp/"))
                    {
                        //start and ends string from the sitemindersession is in the link on the page
                        e.WebTest.Context.Add(this.ContextParameterName, GetStringBetween(ItemMatch.ToString(), "/idp/", "/resume"));
                        e.Success = true;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                e.Success = false;
                e.Message = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Not Found in Link : /idp/");
            }
            else
            {
                e.Success = false;
                e.Message = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "No href tags found");
            }
        }

        public static string GetStringBetween(string token, string first, string second)
        {
            if (!token.Contains(first)) return "";

            var afterFirst = token.Split(new[] { first }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

            if (!afterFirst.Contains(second)) return "";

            var result = afterFirst.Split(new[] { second }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];

            return result;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to have use extraction rule that gets the `**RANDOMURLSTRING**` then change the URLs in the requests to be, for example, `HTTPS://SITE/idp/{{TheRandomString}}/resumeSAML20/idp/startSSO.ping` where `TheRandomString` is the context parameter that holds the extracted value. Note the doubled curly braces (`{{` and `}}`) around the context parameter.

Suppose a value returned by the first redirection needs to be captured but a normal web test would redirect again and so the response is not seen by the extraction rules. In this case need to handle the redirect explicitly. Set the `Follow redirects` property of the initial request to false then add extraction rule(s) to gather the wanted values. Add a new request after the initial request and use the extracted values in it as necessary. It is possible to extract the entire redirected url and set the `Url` field to the extracted value.