# Visual Studio Web Load Test Site Minder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, load-testing, siteminder

I am getting an error with a Siteminder login using vs web tests. I am using an extraction rule to handle the SessionID in redirected URLs. See this question if you are trying to do the same. 
[Visual Studio Load Test redirect URL from Siteminder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310726/visual-studio-load-test-redirect-url-from-siteminder/40317972#40317972)

Everything seems fine until the Java Script page redirect.
[image]

Then I get an error at the next step.  It appears the cookie is not handled properly. I spoke to a siteminder expert and he says the error is cookie related.
[image]
[image]

What am I missing in my test? I read that VS Load Tests handle cookies automatically. Can anyone point me in the right direction here. I could even use a coded webtest and add it at the start.

A litte more information.
I examined the cookies generated in Friefox. I can see the cookie in the cookie manager. However it is not listed in any of the requests in Visual Studio.